# How to log values to Minecraft server terminal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to get some values from my game and into a text format that I can copy/paste outside of Minecraft. I believe the only way to do this is though the terminal but I'm unsure.

The values are stored in a scoreboard variable.
The values must be "logged" multiple times per second.

I own/host the server myself if I need to edit it. Currently Using latest 1.20.1 Bukkit server (can install plugins for it), I need to preferably use datapacks to log the data.

So far, I feel that I need to combine `/say` with `/tellraw`, as I `/say` can log the data to my server terminal and `/tellraw` lets me insert my needed data.

Comment: Kill a named villager? ;)

Comment: Saddly, I dont think I can name a villager to a value in a scoreboard (According to: https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/9kxeny/storing_a_scoreboard_value_in_a_mobs_name/)

Never mind, This looks promising

Comment: Nope, Still not working.

Comment: More seriously: Can't you just spam chat and read `latest.log` afterwards? I even have a convenient script for it here: https://github.com/Fabian42/bash_scripts/blob/35739e4cb7efba1bff45191c29d5b8dc6b511b22/.bashrc#L495 (Adjust your Minecraft folder path.)

Comment: Thats what im doing at the moment. Just hardcoding everything. Was just trying to see if there was a "cleaner" way of doing it. - Cheers for the script thats useful

Comment: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Raw_JSON_text_format